# React Native Rich Text Editor Decorator

Tags: react-native, draftjs

I am wondering if there is anything like DraftJS for React Native to render custom component in a chat.

In DraftJS we are using decorators with a strategy to render e.g. an immutable custom component when the text includes a pattern like {{placeholder}}.

From my research I found that there is a React Native Port for DraftJS (https://github.com/DaniAkash/react-native-draftjs) but this does not allow for these advanced use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a library that supports this, yet. But, I think you can achieve this with a [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)

But my concern is the performance if there are too many instances of it inside a List.

```
const htmlFromChatConvo = '<h1>Hello, {{placeholder}}</h1>'

<WebView
   source={{ 
    html: htmlFromChatConvo
            .replace('{{placeholder}}', 'there!') }}

/>
```